# Swift equivalent of [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]

Tags: swift

What is swift equivalent of next code:

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]
```

I need load resources from test bundle (JSON data)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Never used, but I think it should be this:

**Swift <= 2.x**

```
NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

Comment: Autocomplete in the current version of Xcode acts like it has no idea what you're talking about, but it does indeed work.

Comment: in version 2.1: NSBundle(forClass: self)

Comment: The evolution thread to consider changing this is at https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md

Comment: The solution doesn't work for value types. Consider using `init?(identifier: String)` where identifier is your target's bundle ID. Another solution for value types is to declare an empty class inside your value type. Example of the latter solution: `Bundle(for: Foo.Bar.self)` where `Foo` - your struct, `Bar` - some inner class.

Comment: This doesn't work in Swift 3.1. `type(of: self)` will return `ClassName.Type` and calling `Bundle(for:)` to that **returns the main bundle**

Answer (score 40):

Swift 3:

```
Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

Comment: The solution doesn't work for value types. Consider using `init?(identifier: String)` where identifier is your target's bundle ID. If you don't want to hardcode the bundle ID, use `Bundle(for: Foo.Bar.self)` where `Foo` - your struct, `Bar` - some inner class.

Answer (score 26):

Swift 5

```
Bundle(for: Self.self)
```

Answer (score 12):

I personally like:

```
let bun = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are working on a class then

```
Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

Sometimes you may work in a struct, then you need to use any class in the bundle

```
Bundle(for: AnyClassInTheBundle.self)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:object_getClass(self))
```

Answer (score 8):

The selected answer did not work for me in a static method of a UIView subclass, but I found this:

```
Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)
```

This also works when you want to get the `Bundle` within a test target.

Answer (score 4):

**Loading the xib for dynamicType of the class**

```
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CellForAlert", bundle: bundle)
    let view =  nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(view);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 3.0, you can use:

```
func kZWGetBundle() -> Bundle{
    return Bundle(for: AnyClass.self as! AnyClass)
}
```

Comment: It just crashes

Comment: Crashes for me too, down voted for using force unwrap in sample code.